# How can I have gradle to output info infomation(logs) by default?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I found that by using `-i` and `-d` flags gradle can output info and debug information/logs.
Somthing like below -

`./gradlew myprj:integrationTest -i`  #outputs info information/logs

But rather than passing `-i` flag on command line I want to set this options through gradle scripts i.e `build.gradle` etc. (Since on the remote build server I cannot pass the `-i` option yet)

I tried below in `build.gradle` file - but it did not help. I don't get info level log with below.

```
test {
        testLogging {
            events 'passed', 'failed', 'standardOut', 'standardError'
            info.events  'STARTED', 'PASSED', 'SKIPPED', 'FAILED', 'STANDARD_OUT', 'STANDARD_ERROR'
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**
I could get hold of the logger for `integrationTest`.

```
tasks.named('integrationTest') {
    doFirst {
        def logger = getLogger()
        def originalLevel = logger.isInfoEnabled()
        print 'info logging enabled: ' + originalLevel  //output false
    }
}
```

But there is NO `setLevel` method/prop etc for the `logger`.